# HTML5 - position h1 text next its image

Tags: javascript, css, html, seo

I'm trying to put in an HEADER tag a H1 tag next to a logo image as below:

```css
/* line 1, ../scss/layout/_header.scss */
header {
  background: white;
  color: red;
  height: 100px;
}

header img.logoImage{
    width:30px;
    height:30px;
}
/* line 6, ../scss/layout/_header.scss */
header h1#companyName {
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 20px;
    
}
/* line 10, ../scss/layout/_header.scss */
header h1#companyName a .logoImage {

}
```

```html
   <header>     
     <h1 id="companyName">
      <a href="#" title="Company Website">
        <img class="logoImage" title="" src="https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSd51Q5z8j6c_EBEYzZgU1pfyiGHxOUgchpUs9wC3eaFn6PrXfqe8kjWA" alt="Company Name"/>
          Company name
      </a>    
    </h1>           
   </header>
```

The thing is that "Some title" is not showing as it stays underneath the image.
Also, is this a good way to implement it? (SEO etc etc)

Could you please shed some light on it?

Thanks!

Comment: "Some title" shouldn't be showing under anything. It is an alt attribute and will be displayed (in most browsers) as a tooltip. I can't reproduce the problem you describe with the code you've provided.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. So, what do you suggest alternatively?

Comment: Either describe the problem that the code you are showing us gives you or show us the code that demonstrates the problem you describe.

Comment: Thanks!  Here is the related jsFiddle demo --> http://jsfiddle.net/beppe0/hpjy81pL/

Comment: Why are you using an `img` element and then putting a background image on it? Where is the (mandatory) `src` attribute? Why is most of the on JS Fiddle not in the question?

Comment: Sorry you are right. My mistake. I've updated the jsFiddle --> http://jsfiddle.net/beppe0/hpjy81pL/2/  ....is this an acceptable option?

Comment: I still don't understand what you are asking. Nothing is under the image. Are you asking how to align the vertical middle of the image to the middle of the text?

Comment: What I'm asking is: 1) is it correct sematically?   2) how can I align the img to the middle of the text?

Answer (score 0):

You can try css after selector:

```
.logoImage:after { content:attr(alt);}
```